# SSL not verified in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl

I have a SSL cert that verifies fine in all browsers but IE, and I have no idea why.

Comment: Could you provide the URL of the site that has this cert?

Comment: Without more information about the failure (specific text of any messages) and the certificate, neither does anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

If the certificate is a wildcard cert, note that IE only allows "*" to represent one DNS label (e.g. no dots in it).

However, as others have noted, the only way to get a real answer is to provide the URL of the site so we can take a look.